# How to execute code when application is closing?

Tags: android, realm, android-lifecycle

I am a Junior and I encounter a problem.

I am using Realm on Android (Java) and I would like to delete the data in my local BDD when it is closing. I always finish my activity before starting a new one and I never know what will be the last activity before user decided to close app.

Is there a way to execute code when app is closing?

EDIT

Here's my code, thanks to @Mohanad

```
public class ApplicationClass extends Application {

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    Realm.init(this);

    RealmConfiguration mRealmConfig = new RealmConfiguration.Builder()
            .schemaVersion(1)
            .migration(new RealmMigrations())
            .inMemory()
            .build();

    Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(mRealmConfig);

    registerActivityLifecycleCallBack();

    Log.i("XXX", "I've been created");

}

public void registerActivityLifecycleCallBack() {

    ActivityLifecycleCallbacks mActivity = new ActivityLifecycleCallbacks() {
        int mCounter = 0;

        @Override
        public void onActivityCreated(Activity activity, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            mCounter++;
            Log.i("XXX", "I'm called again and again");
        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityStarted(Activity activity) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityResumed(Activity activity) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityPaused(Activity activity) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityStopped(Activity activity) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onActivitySaveInstanceState(Activity activity, Bundle outState) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityDestroyed(Activity activity) {
            mCounter--;

            if (mCounter == 0) {
                Realm mRealm  = Realm.getDefaultInstance();

                mRealm.close();
            }
        }
    };
}
}
```

Comment: If you want to delete the Realm when the application is no longer running, then just use `.inMemory()` configuration.

Comment: It's what I finally ended up to do. But I can't close my Realm since the only moment where I should close it is when I close my application. Which leads back to my main problem.

Comment: I figured that's why they made it so that you can `Realm.getDefaultInstance()` and `realm.close()` in `onCreate/onDestroy` respectively.

Comment: And that was my best solution! It works perfectly. Pandas always rule the world. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steps:

1.) use `inMemory()` configuration

```
RealmConfiguration config = new RealmConfiguration.Builder()
                                    .inMemory()
                                    .build();
```

2.) Call `realm.init()` in `Application.onCreate()`, set the default configuration as usual, and afterwards, initialize/close Realm like this:

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Realm realm;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        realm.close();
    }
}
```

Now when Realm is closed on all threads and you are quitting the app (or the app is killed), the Realm will be deleted.

Comment: It is exactly what I did! Glad I had this one correct. Thank you again for helping out!

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest solution is using a counter and [ActivityLifecycleCallbacks](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks) in your application class as below:

```
    registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(new ActivityLifecycleCallbacks() {
            int activityCounter = 0;

            @Override
            public void onActivityCreated(Activity activity, Bundle bundle) {
                activityCounter ++;
            }

            @Override
            public void onActivityStarted(Activity activity) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onActivityResumed(Activity activity) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onActivityPaused(Activity activity) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onActivityStopped(Activity activity) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onActivitySaveInstanceState(Activity activity, Bundle bundle) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onActivityDestroyed(Activity activity) {
                activityCounter--;
                if (activityCounter == 0) {
                    //last activity on destroy
                }
            }
        });
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: I'm going to try this!

Comment: it doesn't seem to work. When I debug it, it never goes into it.

Comment: make sure you call registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks in your application onCreate()

Comment: Should I call  register's method in each Activity? When I'm starting the app, it goes into it but when I'm navigating through my app, it never goes back into it.

Comment: You can add the log statement in onActivityCreated(Activity activity, Bundle bundle) to make sure its called every time any activity is created. also you can add a toast message instead of the comment so you can make sure that when you click back and exit the app a toast message is shown

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200602/discussion-between-lena-and-mohanad-alkhouli).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for but maybe this helps.

In your onDestroy check the isTaksRoot() -> method of activity to see if it is the task root.
[isTaskRoot docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#isTaskRoot())

Answer (score -1):

use onDestroy() method and write you code inside it.